# How to list users of Google Admin Directory but exclude users in any sub OU

Tags: google-apps-script, google-admin-sdk

I have one main organizational unit which includes most of my users in the Google Admin Directory.
However I also have some sub-organizational units under the main one which also contain users.

To retrieve all users I am using the [Directory API](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users/list). When I want only to retrieve users of one sub- organizational unit I add `orgUnitPath:/MainOU/subOU1` as a query parameter.

But how can I only retrieve users which are in the main OU but **NOT** in any sub OU? When I use `orgUnitPath:/MainOU` it also includes all users in any sub OU.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Unfortunately the scope of [query](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/search-users)  for [Users: list](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users/list?) is rather limited

- It does not implement the functionality of excluding sub OUs.
- If this functionality is important to you, consider filing a feature request on [Google's Public Issue Tracker](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker)
- In the mean time, a workaround would be performing multiple requests:

  - One request to list the users of the sub OU(s)
  - The second request to list all users
  - Subsequently you need to implement programmatically a functionality to compare the two lists a retrieve only the users that are not contained in the subdomain list

Comment: Well how do I get all sub OUs of one OU? This only works when I already know all sub OU(s) of one OU right?

Comment: ok I got it: https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/orgunits/list
this is really a pain...

Comment: Yes, once you retrieve all the orgUnits through list, you can query `orgUnitPath=/subOU1`, `orgUnitPath=/subOU2` etc. Unfortunately there does not seem to be a better way as of now, but if you implement it into a for loop it should not be to painful.